# Play video on Unity without extension

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have this problem, i created an application that play videos but this video haven't extension , so per example i have video like

```
big_buck_bunny
```

instead a file like :

```
big_buck_bunny.mp4
```

I cant convert this video.
There is a way to play a video from remote without extension?
I have a url like :

```
D:\\Software\\Marmotta\\marmotta-home\\resources\\88\\95\\43\\big_buck_bunny
```

Thanks all for help

Comment: You should show the code of how you got `D:\\Software\\Marmotta\\marmotta-home\\resources\\88\\95\\43\\big_buck_bunny` [as a edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38125069/edit) perhaps there is a way to fix the original problem and get the file extension when you get the url.

Comment: I cant show you the code because i havent, i take this file from a database ( marmotta ) that some people give to me

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the extension at the end of the file?

```
String path = "D:\\Software\\Marmotta\\marmotta-home\\resources\\88\\95\\43\\big_buck_bunny";
path += @".mp4";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all files in a folder filtered to your filename. Be sure to include `using System.IO;` at thte top of the file.

```
var path = "D:\\Software\\Marmotta\\marmotta-home\\resources\\88\\95\\43\\big_buck_bunny"
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
var filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, filename + ".*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

the array `files` will hold a list of all the files in the folder that started with the name `big_buck_bunny`, one of those files will be the one you want to use.